# Count number of tables in Oracle

Tags: oracle, select, count

Like MySQL has "SHOW TABLES" , how do you count tables in Oracle DB. Little bit of research gave me this query:

```
select owner, count(*) from dba_tables
```

So like MySQL has a standard command, does Oracle have one?

Comment: wats stopping u , just execute it and see ?

Comment: Well i dont have oracle on my machine, i run mysql

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Yeah sure your query will work just modify it a little. Look here for refrence : http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14237/statviews_2105.htm#i1592091

Run this:

```
SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM DBA_TABLES;
```

to get list of tables.

and  Run this:

```
SELECT Count(*) FROM DBA_TABLES;
```

to get the count of tables.

Comment: or `SELECT TABLE_NAME, COUNT(*) OVER () FROM DBA_TABLES` to get both.

Comment: If you don't have DBA access or your DBA has restricted that you will need to issue this command:
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM USER_TABLES;

Answer (score 49):

try:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM USER_TABLES;
```

> Well i dont have oracle on my machine, i run mysql  (OP comment)

at the time of writing, [this site](http://sqlzoo.net/howto/source/z.dir/tip318780/oracle) was great for testing on a variety of database types.

Comment: This works on Oracle when DBA_TABLES didn't work since I don't have admin access (and can't get it).

Answer (score 15):

> Select count(*) FROM all_tables where owner='schema_name'

Answer (score 4):

Please find below - its the simplest one I use :

```
select owner, count(*) from dba_tables group by owner;
```

Answer (score 3):

These documents describe data dictionary views:

all_tables: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14237/statviews_4473.htm#REFRN26286

user_tables: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14237/statviews_2105.htm#i1592091

dba_tables: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14237/statviews_4155.htm#i1627762

You can run queries on these views to count what you need.

To add something more to @Anurag Thakre's answer:

> Use this query which will give you the actual no of counts respect to
>   the owners
>
> ```
> SELECT COUNT(*),tablespace_name  FROM USER_TABLES group by tablespace_name;
> ```

Or by table owners:

```
SELECT COUNT(*), owner  FROM ALL_TABLES group by owner;
```

Tablespace itself does not identify an unique object owner. Multiple users can create objects in the same tablespace and a single user can create objects in various tablespaces. 
It is a common practice to separate tables and indexes into different tablespaces.

Answer (score 2):

If you'd like a list of owners, and the count of the number of tables per owner, try:

```
    SELECT distinct owner, count(table_name) FROM dba_tables GROUP BY owner;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to know the number of tables that belong to a certain schema/user, you can also use SQL similar to this one:

```
SELECT Count(*) FROM DBA_TABLES where OWNER like 'PART_OF_NAME%';
```

Answer (score 0):

```
REM setting current_schema is required as the 2nd query depends on the current user referred in the session

ALTER SESSION SET CURRENT_SCHEMA=TABLE_OWNER;

SELECT table_name,
         TO_NUMBER (
            EXTRACTVALUE (
               xmltype (
                  DBMS_XMLGEN.getxml ('select count(*) c from ' || table_name)),
               '/ROWSET/ROW/C'))
            COUNT
    FROM dba_tables
   WHERE owner = 'TABLE_OWNER'
ORDER BY COUNT DESC;
```

Answer (score -1):

Use this query which will give you the actual no of counts in respect to the table owners

```
SELECT COUNT(*),tablespace_name  FROM USER_TABLES group by tablespace_name;
```

Answer (score -2):

```
select COUNT(*) from ALL_ALL_TABLES where OWNER='<Database-name>';
```

.....

Answer (score -2):

THIS QUERY WILL FIND ALL THE OBJECTS COUNTS IN A SPECIFIC SCHEMA

```
select owner, object_type, count(*) from dba_objects where owner='owner_name' group by owner, object_type order by 3 desc;
```